# Deploying owncloud on goddady gives warning and parse error

Tags: php, owncloud

i am getting error while deploying owncloud on godaddy server

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/content/73/8989273/html/files/lib/app.php on line 611

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/73/8989273/html/files/lib/app.php on line 611
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is old and outdated, nevertheless the basic problem might still occur for others. So I think it makes sense to to give a general answer to this:

owncloud requires php version 5.3 or greater. That version introduced `namespaces`, the backslash character that the named system claims to be a syntax error is such a namespace notation. So most likely the named service simply runs an outdated version of php (some version older than 5.3). Such versions are depreciated anyway, the service provider is stronly encouraged to upgrade, since older versions are insecure and not supported any more.